# Microsoft Graph scopes v2 oauth

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to build a simple Ruby application that can connect to the Microsoft Graph API and get basic information about the user, for example the manager or direct reports.

I've followed a 0365-tutorial and i've got a working app that is able to get a user's mail. However when I try to then use the session tokens to query the graph api, i get an error:

```
response.body
=> "{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"InvalidAuthenticationToken\",\r\n    \"message\": \"Access token validation failure.\",\r\n    \"innerError\": {\r\n      \"request-id\": \"18cbc6be-5254-400c-9780-7427376587fb\",\r\n      \"date\": \"2016-06-30T22:21:55\"\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}"
```

I'm using scopes

```
SCOPES = [ 'openid', 'profile', 'https://outlook.office.com/contacts.read', 'offline_access' ]
```

I've just been suggested to include the scope 'https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read', but when i add this to the application i get the following error before even hitting the user login page:

```
AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope openid profile offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read is not valid.
```

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you post the full URL that you're using to access the login page?

Comment: https://login.microsoftonline.com

Comment: I mean with all of the parameters :). You can copy it from the browser when you land on the error.

Comment: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=c9c7bdc1-9cea-4ea4-8082-f885b046fd60&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauthorize&response_type=code&scope=openid+profile+https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office.com%2Fcontacts.read+offline_access+https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok. The problem is that you are including scopes for both Outlook (the `https://outlook.office.com/contacts.read` scope) and Graph (the `https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read` scope). Unfortunately Azure's authorization endpoint doesn't support mixing scopes like that. You can either remove the Outlook scope (assuming you don't need it), or change it to the Graph equivalent: `https://graph.microsoft.com/contacts.read` (if you need to access the logged on user's personal contacts).

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason. I can now do at least /me :)

Comment: When i try to get the direct reports i get an error saying: code: Authorization_RequestDenied, message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation." Do you know if there's a resource with the scopes and whether some of them are only accessible to admins?

Comment: It looks like the Graph docs have a mistake. The link for direct reports says User.Read will work, but http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes says with User.Read you cannot read "navigation properties like manager and direct reports." Let me ask the Graph folks what's going on.

Comment: I've found this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes#PermissionScopeConcepts which says that in order to get information about managers and direct reports an administrator has to consent to it... so end up in a screen with this error: AADSTS90093: Calling principal cannot consent due to lack of permissions. Wondering how is it that one gets consent for an app in dev :) also, not even sure who my admin even is to consent to this... we're in a 100K employees company!

Comment: I reproduce this, I'm checking with the Graph folks for confirmation that this is intended.

Comment: I also see that User.Read should be enough here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_directreports.md

Comment: I got confirmation from the Graph folks that it **does** require admin consent, by design. Let them know your thoughts on this here: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/ :)

Comment: Having similar problem with EWS at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366134/utilizing-oauth2-for-office365-through-exchange-activesync-eas . Can you help?