# Utilizing OAuth2 for Office365, through Exchange ActiveSync (EAS)

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365, activesync

The blog post: [Announcing Exchange ActiveSync v16.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2016/06/13/announcing-exchange-activesync-version-16-1/) states that:

> While not a part of EAS 16.1, we also want to note that both Office 365 and Outlook.com customers can now utilize the OAuth 2.0 protocol for authorization through EAS.

My question is: which **scope** should I use in the oauth request?

Is there an example, perhaps of the full request?

*Note*: there was a similar question about [using OAuth for Office365 with IMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747477/), but here I'm specifically asking about **ActiveSync**. I referenced this question in a [comment to one of the answers on that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747477/imap-auth-in-office-365-using-oauth2#comment69917914_29747829).

**Secondary problem**:

Thanks to Jason's answer and some additional tweaks, we managed to generate oauth token using https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2 but only for office365 users (*Organization Accounts*) and not to Microsoft *users account* (live, hotmail, outlook.com...)

The token allows access to both ActiveSync protocol (via https://eas.outlook.com/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync) and for EWS API (via https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx).

Unfortunately we cannot find a way to generate same token for Microsoft *online* accounts (hotmail, live, outlook.com). We tried using this endpoint: https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf which allow only activesync and not EWS.

Is there a way to use the same token for both organization and online accounts on both protocols (ActiveSync and EWS)?

Comment: I have the same question! Did you figure it out?

Comment: No. I'm still hoping to find an answer...

Answer (score 2):

Sorry this took so long, but I wasn't aware of this question until today :). You need to register your app as a native application in Azure Active Directory:

[image]

Then add the **Access mailboxes as the signed-in user via Exchange Web Services** (under **Office 365 Exchange Online**) delegated permission.

**NOTE:** You cannot register this in the Application Registration Portal (https://apps.dev.microsoft.com), it needs to be registered in the Azure Portal (https://portal.azure.com/), and you need to use the [v1 Azure auth endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) for authorization and token requests.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, there's a second problem: we need to use the same token for both office365 users and online users (hotmail, live, etc). I added the full description to the question.

Comment: The Azure v1 endpoints do not support Microsoft accounts (Hotmail, Outlook.com, etc.). They only support Office 365.

Comment: Is there a way of having both account types (and both EWS and ActiveSync) work with a single oauth token? We tried with LiveConnect, but it only worked for MS accounts.

Comment: No, there's no way. The EWS scope isn't exposed on Azure's v2 endpoints, which is the only endpoint that supports converged auth (meaning that both work and personal accounts can authenticate).

Comment: OK. What would be the oauth scope and endpoint for personal account (hotmail) that works with EWS?

Comment: I don't believe there is one, but I'm double-checking that.

Comment: I am running into the same issue and I see that Jason Johnston was double checking but did not post back to this thread. Is there a way to use OAUTH2 for an Outlook.com account so that it can work with EWS?